# Copy and Pasting virtual environment to work on another machine

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualenv

Before my hdd got destroyed I was working on this virtual environment.
Where I have installed all the necessary packages like `python`, jupyter notebook. I used to run jupyter notebook using terminal. Then I replaced my hdd and copied the whole virtual environment. But now its saying permission denied.

There was an article explaining you need to use chmod u+x `appname` but it is not working

Previously I used to write in terminal like.
    source virtualenvironment/bin/activate
    jupyter-notebook

After entering jupyter-notebook it should run the notebook

Answer (score 0):

Simply copying and pasting will not work as there may be paths that are not being set. So you simply need to create virtual environment again with same name. Then inside the virtual environment you need to install the same packages. Note that all the requirements must be fulfilled but this time the paths are also set. So running packages now will work fine.